# Download an entire public folder from Google-Drive using Python or wget/curl without authentication

Tags: download, python-requests, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I would like to download an entire public folder from Google-drive from script (python, wget, terminal, etc.).
The procedure shall be accomplished without authentication, as it's a public folder which is accessible for anyone who has the link.

Link example:   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Gt-W8jMrADizXYGF5QZwJh_Gc8QpKflX

In case that it's not possible to directly download the entire folder, then it would be sufficient to just being able to list its content (files), without authentication, and then I'll be able to download each file separately. How to obtain such a listing feature?

**Note**:
I found many similar discussions, but all were assuming either file-download or authentication, and I couldn't find a match for that specific ask, e.g.:

- [Python: How do download entire folder from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52619878/python-how-do-download-entire-folder-from-google-drive)
- [download folder from google drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67045640/download-folder-from-google-drive)
- [Download entire Google Drive folder from the shared link using Google drive API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345750/download-entire-google-drive-folder-from-the-shared-link-using-google-drive-api)
- [How to download specific Google Drive folder using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39003409/how-to-download-specific-google-drive-folder-using-python)
- [Download Shared Google Drive Folder with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857900/download-shared-google-drive-folder-with-python)
- [Python: download files from google drive using url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38511444/python-download-files-from-google-drive-using-url)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136371/how-to-download-a-folder-from-google-drive-using-terminal
- https://github.com/vikynandha-zz/google-drive-backup/blob/master/drive.py

Comment: In your situation, for example, is this CLI tool useful? https://github.com/tanaikech/goodls But, when the files in the public folder, at least, it is required to use an API key because the file list is required to be retrieved from the public folder. If this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, it surely seems relevant and I wasn’t aware of that CLI. I will give it a try, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. If that was not useful for your situation, I apologize. And, if you cannot use the API key, for example, how about creating the file list from the public folder by manual operation or Google Apps Script? By this, you can download the files without the API key.

Comment: That's an excellent idea, thanks Tanaike. I also found this Google Apps Script, with your inspiration, thanks --> https://gist.github.com/mesgarpour/07317e81e9ee2b3f1699

Comment: Thank you for replying. If your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up applying the following code (tested, works well):

```
import urllib.request
from getfilelistpy import getfilelist
from os import path, makedirs, remove, rename

def download_googledrive_folder(remote_folder, local_dir, gdrive_api_key, debug_en):

    success = True

    if debug_en:
        print('[DEBUG] Downloading: %s --> %s' % (remote_folder, local_dir))
    else:
        try:
            resource = {
                "api_key": gdrive_api_key,
                "id": remote_folder.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0],
                "fields": "files(name,id)",
            }
            res = getfilelist.GetFileList(resource)
            print('Found #%d files' % res['totalNumberOfFiles'])
            destination = local_dir
            if not path.exists(destination):
                makedirs(destination)
            for file_dict in res['fileList'][0]['files']:
                print('Downloading %s' % file_dict['name'])
                if gdrive_api_key:
                    source = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%s?alt=media&key=%s" % (file_dict['id'], gdrive_api_key)
                else:
                    source = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download" % file_dict['id']  # only works for small files (<100MB)
                destination_file = path.join(destination, file_dict['name'])
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(source, destination_file)

        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            success = False

    return success
```

I could not find a way to achieve my original goal, i.e. downloading public folder from Google-Drive without any credentials/keys, but the above code is a good compromise for me, as it only requires a key and not full credentials.

Note that there are 2 options here --> with or without providing the Google API Key (*gdrive_api_key*) for the source URL.
From my experience, the option without the API key works well for small files (< ~100MB), while the option with the API key appear to be more robust and works for any size.

Comment: What is getfilelistpy?

Comment: Hi Mehmet, see https://pypi.org/project/getfilelistpy

Comment: Huge thanks, i was thinking that it's a py file in your local, not open source project.